# No puedo activar la conexión bluetooth en Ubuntu 18.04 (falta de adaptador)

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

tengo el siguiente problema: instalé los paquetes correspondientes a blueman, bluez, etc. y al ejecutar:

`sudo rfkill list` 
 solo me aparece el estado del LAN, ningún rastro del bluetooth. Utilicé también los comandos

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

y

```
sudo service bluetooth start
```

y appareció e ícono de bluetooth en la esquina superior derecha de la pantalla, pero a abrir el administrador de bluetooth me aparecen las ventanas de Adaptadores y Dispositivos en gris, sin posibilidad de poder clickearlas para acceder a las preferencias de la conexión y enlazar dispositivos:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además, en Configuración, no puedo activar el bluetooth debido a que no tengo ningún adaptador, lo que coincide con la ventana en gris de la imagen anterior. No puedo deslizar a perilla para activarlo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya, agradezco su ayuda.